# implement bootstrap notification or profile

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

```
good morning:
 <html>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Notifications <span class="badge badge-light">4</span>
 </button>


 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Profile <span class="badge badge-light">9</span>
   <span class="sr-only">unread messages</span>
 </button>
</html>
```

[image]

now how I implement these ?
for example like facebook when i click the notification appear a little submenu

anyone can help me ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the notifications from the database in your controller, put them in a variable, and pass it to a view.

In the view itself you can do something like this:

```
// $notificationsCount is the variable with number of notifications you passed to the 
view in your controller
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Notifications 
    <span class="badge badge-light"><?php echo $notificationsCount ?></span>
</button>
```

If you don't want to refresh the page, you could use ajax or some kind of event.
Example:

```
$('#someElement').on('click', function () {
    //change value of the notification btn
});
```